# Two R Error Messages When Attempting To Predict Via Single Index Model

Tags: r, error-handling, syntax-error, regression

I am attempting to use the Single Index model to estimate alpha beta and sigma2_ei for 3 stocks and the TSX. Here is my current R code

**Importing the Data**

```
setwd("~/Desktop/R Data Sets") Ass2Data1 <- read.csv("~/Desktop/R Data     Sets/Ass2DataSheet1.csv") View(Ass2Data1)
```

**Transforming the data into matrix form**

```
b <- as.matrix(Ass2Data1)
```

**Generating Initial Vectors and Matrices**

```
x <- rep(0,60) 
xx <- matrix(x, ncol=4, nrow=3)
stock <- rep(0,3) 
alpha <- rep(0,3) 
beta <- rep(0,3) 
mse <- rep(0,3) 
Rbar <- rep(0,3) 
Ratio <- rep(0,3)

col1 <- rep(0,3) 
col2 <- rep(0,3) 
col3 <- rep(0,3) 
col4 <- rep(0,3) 
col5 <- rep(0,3)
```

**Regressing each stock on the index and recording results**

```
for(i in 1:3){
alpha[i] <- lm(data=Ass2Data1,formula=Ass2Data1[,1] ~ Ass2Data1[,4]$coefficients[1])
beta[i] <- lm(data=Ass2Data1,formula=Ass2Data1[,2] ~ Ass2Data1[,4]$coefficients[2])
Rbar[i] <- alpha[i]+beta[i]*mean(b[,4])
mse[i] <-sum(lm(data=Ass2Data1,formula=Ass2Data1[,i] ~ Ass2Data1[,4])$residuals2)/(nrow(b)-2)
Ratio[i] <- (Rbar[i]/beta[i])
stock[i] <- i }
```

**Creating table**

```
xx <- (cbind(stock,alpha,beta,Rbar,mse,Ratio))
```

However I keep getting the following error messages:

Error in Ass2Data1[, 4]$coefficients : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

and

Error in beta[i] * mean(b[, 4]) : non-numeric argument to binary operator

If anybody could point me in the right direction with respect to what I'm doing wrong here it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `?lm`, change the closing `)`

```
alpha[i] <- lm(data=Ass2Data1,formula=Ass2Data1[,1] ~ Ass2Data1[,4])$coefficients[1]
beta[i] <- lm(data=Ass2Data1,formula=Ass2Data1[,2] ~ Ass2Data1[,4])$coefficients[2]
```

Better way is to get coefficients via `coef`:

```
alpha[i] <- coef(lm(data=Ass2Data1,formula=Ass2Data1[,1] ~ Ass2Data1[,4]))[1]
 beta[i] <- coef(lm(data=Ass2Data1,formula=Ass2Data1[,2] ~ Ass2Data1[,4]))[2]
```

Comment: Hey man thanks so much that is working now to store coef! Still getting the non-numeric argument to binary operator error though, tried using *. but R doesn't recognize it

Comment: Great! Please mark it as answered if it solves your problem.